# Having a issue creating switch expression

Tags: reporting-services

I've got small problem with Switch expression, I know it's something easy however...

```
=Switch(Fields!Info2.Value > 61, "1, ", Fields!Info2.Value < 61, "2, ", Fields!Info2.Value < 57, "3,", Fields!Info2.Value <= 53, "")
```

Values between 62 and 64 shows 1
Values between 58 and 60 shows 2
Values between 54 and 56 shows 3

I need expression to skip values above 64 and below 53 and also not include 57,61

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=Switch(
    Fields!Info2.Value >= 62 And Fields!Info2.Value <= 64, "1, ", 
    Fields!Info2.Value >= 58 And Fields!Info2.Value <= 60, "2, ", 
    Fields!Info2.Value >= 54 And Fields!Info2.Value <= 56, "3, ", 
    True, ""
)
```

Probably the last case in the Switch function is useless because you do nothing with other values.